# How to configure gsm modem for sending sms in text mode with ucs2 set of characters?

Tags: sms, ucs2

I try to send sms in text mode with UCS2 set of characters.
Phone number is an exmaple +48555555555 and message is "Hello". When i execute this, I get "+CMS ERROR: Invalid PDU mode parameter". There is my code for sending sms:

```
mUsart.TranmistText("AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"\r\n");
vTaskDelay(2000);
mUsart.TranmistText("AT+CSMP=17,168,0,8\r\n");
vTaskDelay(2000);
mUsart.TranmistText("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
vTaskDelay(2000);
mUsart.TranmistText("AT+CMGS=\"002B00340038003500350035003500350035003500350035\"\r\n");
vTaskDelay(50);
mUsart.TranmistText("00480065006C006C006F\u001a");
```

I sent phone number as +48555555555 and still doesn't work.

Comment: `TranmistText` ? I don't even know what programming language this is supposed to be, but my first hunch would be to fix the most basic errors.